# Codeigniter: Firm unique validation not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback

I have tried almost everything in my knowledge and found on net but nothing works. What I am trying to do is while adding new record I want to check whether the field value is already in database table or not. If not than add else throw error message.

I have tried also with `is_usnique` but than it is not allowing to modify data since it is considering that form value is exists.

Table name is **positions**
Coloumn name is **position**
Input field name is **position**

I have tried below code in my Controller

```
public function _unique_poscode()
{        
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->db->where('position', $this->input->post('position'));        
    !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
    $poses = $this->positions_model->get();

    if (count($poses)) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_unique_poscode', '%s should be uinique');
        return FALSE;   
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And set rules in my Model as below

```
public $rules               =   array(        
    'position' => array(
            'field' => 'position',
            'label' => 'Position Code',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[10]|callback__unique_poscode|xss_clean'
        ),
    'label' => array(
            'field' => 'label',
            'label' => 'Position Label',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean'
        ),                                               

    );
```

but no matter whatever I do it is not working and adding record even if it is exists in table.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you dont need callback for this there is already funcion made by codeigniter.

Comment: Can you please provide me some reference code or any reference link to see how to workout on that?

Comment: Have you ever try to use `is_unique['table_name'.'field_name']` on `rules?

Comment: @fawwaz I have tried that already but it is validating on edit form as well which is not good. Due to that not able to modify the data even

Answer (score 0):

you are missing parameter

```
public function _unique_poscode( $p )
{        

    $this->form_validation->set_message('_unique_poscode', '%s should be uinique');
    $q = $this->db->get_where('positions', array('position' => $p));
    return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;   

}
```

and in rules

`...|callback__unique_poscode|trim`

---

and how it is done by codeigniter is as one of rules, please see this for [more](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference)

`is_unique[table.column]`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. BUt how it will consider `_unique_poscode` in `is_unique`?

Comment: It still adds row? and please explain: I have tried also with is_usnique but than it is not allowing to modify data since it is considering that form value is exists. And please edit and add your method that takes care of this.

Comment: Yes it is still adding row after `callback_`. What I mean to say if I use `is_unique` it is considering the same on edit form so it is not allowing to modify data even. The callback function is for ignoring the validation if it is in edit mode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45802/discussion-between-kyslik-and-jatin-soni)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to rules and check.

```
is_unique[TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME]
```

According to your one it should be,

```
is_unique[positions.position]
```